# Issue with Google based sign-in in a Flutter + Firebase project

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have a view where the user can sign in and out, currently email and Google sign in are supported. Signing in with Google works fine, however when the user signs out and then tries to sign in again with Google, nothing happens, a spinner is shown for ever on the 'Sign in' button (waiting before trying to sign in makes no difference).

```
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

class AuthenticationScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthenticationScreen({super.key});

  Future<void> signout() async {
    await _googleSignIn.disconnect();
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const SizedBox(
            height: 600,
            child: SignInScreen(),
          );
        } else {
          return ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              signout();
            },
            child: const Text("Sign out"),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

If I hot reload the app after signing out, sign in works fine. Sp it seems to me that something is not cleaned up or disconnected properly which prevents signing in after signing out, however all the examples I can see do not seem to do much in the way of clean up either...

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one account in the popup and you selects it for the first time then it will take that account automatically for the next time. if there is multiple account then only it will ask to select the account to login. You can check my demo here https://github.com/Ankit-Slnk/flutter-google-auth-demo. you can test it in web also https://flutter-web-google-auth.netlify.app/#/

Comment: Thanks Ankit, but that wasn’t my question. My problem is that if sign out I cannot sign in without restarting the app. Clicking sign in does nothing (a spinner appears on the button, but nothing happens). Hope I managed to describe the problem more clearly now. I will check your demo to see if your version allows me to re-login).

Comment: Had a quick look at how you've implemented sign out, will try it out in my app later today and will update this question with results. Thanks!

Comment: Tried your solution and it seems it works fine on Chrome - but it has the same issue as mine on iPhone. So at this stage it seems to me that there's some extra steps required on the mobile platform (workaround is to kill the app and restart). Also interestingly login with Google doesn't seem to work at all on macOS platform.

Comment: (macOS: when I click on Sign on, a dialogue pops open which remains blank), no error is displayed on the console. (This looks like a known issue for some time: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46157)